# How to Create a For Loop for Copying Data From Different Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I am very new to Visual Basic and I am trying to do a For loop to create a Date-Task combination for my data and I am stuck. So I have two ranges as below, Dates and Tasks. I need to copy the elements of these ranges to a different sheet as one element of Date followed by all the element in Tasks. I am creating a For loop for this and it justs keep shuffling the correct data in the same cells. It should be like cell B2 is 05-07-2021 and cell C2 is Tipping. Then cell B3 is 05-07-2021, cell C3 is Carrying. Then cell B4 is 05-07-2021, cell C4 is Driving. Then cell B5 is 06-07-2021, cell C5 is Tipping. And so on. How can I do this? I have pasted my sample code here.

| Date | Task |
| --- | --- |
| 05/07/2021 | Tipping |
| 06/07/2021 | Carrying |
| 07/07/2021 | Driving |
| 08/07/2021 |  |
| 09/07/2021 |  |

```
Sub CreateIdentifier()

Dim dateRange As Range
Dim taskRange As Range
Dim LastRow1 As Integer
Dim LastRow2 As Integer
    
LastRow1 = Sheet6.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

Set taskRange = Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Cells(2, 4), Sheet5.Cells(LastRow2, 4))
Set dateRange = Sheet6.Range(Sheet6.Cells(2, 1), Sheet6.Cells(LastRow1, 1))


Dim datecnt As Range
Dim taskcnt As Range

With Sheet3
For Each datecnt In dateRange
    For Each taskcnt In taskRange
        .Range("B2") = datecnt.Value
        .Range("C2") = taskcnt.Value
    Next taskcnt
Next datecnt
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are only assigning values for cells B2 and C2. Keep counters for each column and offset by that. Read about range.offset, should be easy enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment a variable to switch rows at each iteration

```
Dim r as Long



r = 2
With Sheet3
    For Each datecnt In dateRange
        For Each taskcnt In taskRange
            .Range("B" & r).Value = datecnt.Value
            .Range("C" & r).Value = taskcnt.Value
            r = r + 1
        Next taskcnt
    Next datecnt
End with
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this and it worked! Appreciated.

Comment: @Umur Torun -- You're welcome. Please consider marking the answer as correct so others know your question was answered